# Trouble with Skype new version

Tags: installation, skype

I had been using Skype successfully for some time. My old laptop needed to replace and when it came I downloaded Skype and used it once with good effect.

I went to use it last night and found the Skype had totally disappeared off my laptop. I reinstalled it and found that it was not the same as I had previously, I had lost contacts, all the photos, telling me if people were on/off line and did not offer me the facility to video call. All it offered me was to call the number, no video and the messages need to pay for!.

I uninstalled it and tried again and still the same situation.

What has happened to Skype it used to be so easy to use and brilliant, now it's unusable for me?

Comment: Did you install skype from Software Center or download it from it's web? I've seen people complain about weir issues when they download it from the site.

Answer (score 0):

> I had lost contacts

The installation of Skype doesn't have anything to do with it. You must contact Skype support

> all the photos

Skype stores photos somewhere, look at `~/.config/skype`, `~/.cache` and `~/.skype`/

> telling me if people were on/off line and did not offer me the facility to video call.

If it doesn't offer the video call and you are sure you should have it contact Skype support.

> All it offered me was to call the number, no video and the messages need to pay for!.

If you need to pay for messages and previously no, check your account via browser to know the services are available for you.